# Permissions to created directories using Yarn

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, npm, yarnpkg

I was trying to setup a command using **Yarn** to create directories, build my Docker images and then launching `docker-compose up`.

I added a *start* script in my `package.json` to execute a **shell script**:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "./start-docker.sh",
  ...
}
```

This is the **start-docker.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p volumes/mysql volumes/wordpress

docker-compose build

docker-compose up
```

It didn't work at first because my containers had no rights to access the created directories.

I then added this line after the creation of the directories in order to give full permissions to containers:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 volumes
```

But as you can see, this command requires to be executed using *sudo*. This means that executing the `yarn start` command asks for a password, thing I didn't want.

I get rid of the *shell script* and used **yarn scripts only**:

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "mkdir -p volumes/mysql volumes/wordpress && docker-compose build",
  "start": "docker-compose up",
  ...
}
```

Surprisingly enough it worked, but I don't understand why.. do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Once the directory has permission 777 it keeps this permission. You sure you recreate everything everytime ?

Comment: No it's not created everytime but still, I need to set the permissions once in order to make it work

Comment: This looks like a matter of users. When `yarn` creates directories and run containers, it works smoothly, but when directories are created by yarn, and run by script, users change. Verify this by using `whoami` at appropriate points.

Comment: @Ayushya it will run under the same user, with the same permissions. I explained whats happening in my answer if you are interested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experience with running "dockerized" node containers, I suggest a *different approach*.

To achieve your goal, we'll take a different approach in which I consider as a *better practice* since it solves the issue at hand and some other un-raised issues as well.

## A Different Approach

The package scripts are meant to run javascript either installed from dependencies or from the package content. The `package.json` file should have the entrances of your node application only, **not to your docker container**.

Now you will have a separate bash file that you run to start node in a "dockerized environment". While the `package.json` runs your node files.

The docker image will contain something similar to the following in its final lines:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["yarn"]
CMD [ "start" ]
```

Since you have extra steps to do before running the image (running `mkdir` locally), you can run `bash ./start-docker.sh` from the command line to run the script, rather than through yarn.

> The docker image will run your `package.json` scripts and not the other way around.

Here are some of the added benefits of having your docker separated from the `package.json`:

1. You get rid of the permissions issues, since running bash directly will allow it to create files and do things that the user that ran it has.
2. It allows non-docker users to access your node application through the `package.json` scripts, just like they are used to do.
3. It allows the users of docker to understand what the docker image is doing, since it will eventually run a `package.json` script after the setup process. It also allows changing the entrance without changing the bash or docker files.
4. The docker `CMD` can be changed at runtime to run different package scripts other than `start` (such as `test` etc).
5. Remove the dependency of docker to run the project, this is important because docker is not installed via `yarn install` making the package a "non-real" package per se.

## Why Yarn is requiring permissions

The core issue is **Not in Yarn**. It is in calling (`“bash ./start-docker.sh”` **vs** `“./start-docker.sh”`).

Running `./start-docker.sh` will require sudo permissions, regardless of running it through yarn or not. Yarn does not do any gimmicks in changing users or such.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "bash ./start-docker.sh",
  ...
}
```

Adding `bash` upfront will solve the issue. Again, I really do **not** recommend this solution. Separate docker from your `package.json`.

### Nitty-gritty details for those interested:

The `./start-docker.sh` requires execution and readable bits, while `bash ./start-docker.sh` only requires readable bit. execution bits require permissions.

You can read more about it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203372).